# Allowing access to hidden folder from web. Plotly-dash

Tags: python, flask, https, plotly-dash, certbot

I think my question can be confusing, but I'll explain it better.

What I want is to have my app return files located in hidden directories using http requests, for instance if I make a `http://mywebsite.com/assets/style.css` request I get the `style.css` file but, I also want to have my app return files from a hidden directory, say `http://mywebsite.com/.hidden-folder/file` (in this case I get a **200** response but without the file requested)

This is a kind of a new problem for me since I am not familiarized with web development, so I don't know where to start.

**Why am I asking this?**

I am using `certbot` for enabling **https** in my website and I need to allow access to `.well-known/acme-challenge/` folder from web and also I am curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

directory structure

```
├── api
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── build
│   ├── .hidden
│   │   └── test.json
```

```
#app.py
app = Flask(__name__,static_folder='../build',static_url_path="/")

@app.route('/hidden/<filename>')
def hello_world2(filename):
    return app.send_static_file(os.path.join(".hidden", filename))

# or

@app.route('/<path>/<filename>')
def hello_world3(path, filename):
    return app.send_static_file(os.path.join(path, filename))
```

```
>> curl 127.0.0.1:5000/hidden/test.json
{
  "test": "test"
}

>> curl 127.0.0.1:5000/.hidden/test.json
{
  "test": "test"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I recently had the same issue, I used `app.server.route` to basically redirect the http01 challenge that looks for files in `.well-known/acme-challenge` to the correct place - in my case a relative path to a public folder. Here's the code I added to `app.py` below the instantiation of `app = dash.Dash(...)`.

```py
import flask
# Certificate http01 challenge
@app.server.route("/.well-known/acme-challenge/<path:filename>")
def http01_respond(filename):
    return flask.send_file(
        "../../public/.well-known/acme-challenge/{}".format(filename)
    )
```

This works on Dash 2.7.1.

This is similar to the post above, but the Flask/Dash differences weren't obvious to me as a novice!

I wrote a post [here](https://www.kragskow.dev/posts/2023/01/blog-post-2/) about it in a bit more detail, but I think the above will suffice for anyone else who gets stuck like I did.